# Trying to implement multiple conditional loop and changing image and content randomly

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I'm Trying to implement a condition such that Tapping on image should change image content and text in different image container and  text block respectively and randomly such that one of the content of Headername should always matches with one of the image in image container and text in text block .
Refer image[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KFYsV.jpg)

Xamlcode

```
<Grid.Background>
            <ImageBrush  ImageSource="Assets/Quiz/bg.png"/>
        </Grid.Background>
        <StackPanel>
            <MediaElement x:Name="mediaElement1" />
        </StackPanel>
        <Popup x:Name ="ppup" IsOpen = "False" IsLightDismissEnabled = "True" Width = "30" HorizontalAlignment = "Left" >
            <Image Source = "Assets/good_job.png" />
        </Popup >
        <Popup x:Name ="ppup1" IsOpen = "False" IsLightDismissEnabled = "True" Width = "30" HorizontalAlignment = "Left" >
            <Image Source = "Assets/wrong_ans.png" />
        </Popup >
        <Grid>
            <Image x:Name="homeBtn"
            Source="Assets/LearnColor/Button/btn_home.png"              
               Height="90" Width="80"
               VerticalAlignment="Top"
               HorizontalAlignment="Right"
               Margin="0,-10,-10,0"/>
        </Grid>
        <Grid>
            <Image x:Name="Header" 
            Source="Assets/Quiz/header_quiz.png"              
               Height="140" Width="350"
               VerticalAlignment="Top"
               Margin="0,-7,0,0"            
               />
            <TextBlock x:Name="HeaderName"
                Text="Yellow"
               VerticalAlignment="Top"
               Margin="290,53,0,0" FontSize="30" FontStyle="Normal" FontWeight="ExtraBold" />
        </Grid>
        <Grid>
        <Image x:Name="imgContainer1"
            Source="Assets/Quiz/object_bg.png"              
               Height="190" Width="200"
               HorizontalAlignment="Left"
               VerticalAlignment="Center"
               Margin="10,60,0,0"/>
            <Image x:Name="image1"
            Source="Assets/LearnColor/Object/ob_0_0.png"              
            Height="150" Width="160"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            VerticalAlignment="Center"
            Margin="30,60,0,0"
            Tapped="image1Tap"
               />
            <Image x:Name="imgContainer2"
            Source="Assets/Quiz/object_bg.png"              
               Height="190" Width="200"
               HorizontalAlignment="Center"
               VerticalAlignment="Center"
               Margin="20,60,0,0"/>
            <Image x:Name="image2"
            Source="Assets/LearnColor/Object/ob_1_0.png"              
               Height="150" Width="160"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Center"
               VerticalAlignment="Center"
                   Margin="20,60,0,0"
                   Tapped="image2Tap"
               />
            <Image x:Name="imgContainer3"
            Source="Assets/Quiz/object_bg.png"              
               Height="190" Width="200"
               HorizontalAlignment="Right"
               VerticalAlignment="Center"
               Margin="0,60,0,0"/>
            <Image x:Name="image3"
            Source="Assets/LearnColor/Object/ob_2_0.png"              
               Height="150" Width="160"
               HorizontalAlignment="Right"
               VerticalAlignment="Center"
                   Margin="0,60,20,0"
                   Tapped="image3Tap"
               />
        </Grid>
        <Grid>
            <Image x:Name="objName1" 
            Source="Assets/Quiz/object_bg_name.png"              
            Height="200" Width="200"
            VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            Margin="10,0,0,0"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="objNameWritten1"
               Text="Banana"
               VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
               HorizontalAlignment="Left"
               Margin="30,0,0,20" FontSize="25" FontStyle="Normal" FontWeight="ExtraBold"
               Tapped="objNameWritten1Tapped"/>
            <Image x:Name="objName2" 
            Source="Assets/Quiz/object_bg_name.png"              
            Height="200" Width="200"
            VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
            Margin="10,0,0,0"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="objNameWritten2"
               Text="Sheep"
               VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
               HorizontalAlignment="Center"
               Margin="0,0,0,20" FontSize="25" FontStyle="Normal" FontWeight="ExtraBold"
              Tapped="objNameWritten2Tapped"/>
            <Image x:Name="objName3" 
            Source="Assets/Quiz/object_bg_name.png"              
            Height="200" Width="200"
            VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
            HorizontalAlignment="Right"
            Margin="10,0,0,0"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="objNameWritten3"
               Text="Berry"
               VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
               HorizontalAlignment="Right"
               Margin="0,0,50,20" FontSize="25" FontStyle="Normal" FontWeight="ExtraBold"
               Tapped="objNameWritten3Tapped"/>
        </Grid>
```

cs code

```
public sealed partial class Quiz : Page
    {
        public class MyImage
        {
            public string Header { get; set; }
            public string image { get; set; }
            public string prevObjBtn { get; set; }
            public string fwdObjBtn { get; set; }
            public string HeaderName { get; set; }
            public string objNameWritten1 { get; set; }
            public string objNameWritten2 { get; set; }
            public string objNameWritten3 { get; set; }
        }
        string[] Headername = new string[] { "Yellow", "white", "red", "purple", "pink", "orange", "green", "grey", "brown", "blue", "black" };
        string[] objnamewritten = new string[] { "Banana", "Sheep", "Berry", "Grapes", "Icecream", "Girrafe", "Tree", "Elephant", "Log", "Sky", "Crow" };
        int CI = 0;
        public Quiz()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void image1Tap(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            common();
        }

        private void image2Tap(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            common();
        }

        private void image3Tap(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            common();
        }

        private void objNameWritten1Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            common();
        }

        private void objNameWritten2Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            common();
        }

        private void objNameWritten3Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            common();
        }

        private void common()
        {            
            if (Headername[CI] == "Yellow")
            {
                if (objNameWritten1.Text=="Banana" || objNameWritten1.Text=="lemomn" || objNameWritten1.Text=="Sun")
                {
                    ppup.Height = Window.Current.Bounds.Height;
                    ppup.IsOpen = true;
                }
                else if (objNameWritten2.Text == "Banana" || objNameWritten2.Text == "lemomn" || objNameWritten2.Text == "Sun")
                {
                    ppup.Height = Window.Current.Bounds.Height;
                    ppup.IsOpen = true;
                }
                else if (objNameWritten3.Text == "Banana" || objNameWritten3.Text == "lemomn" || objNameWritten3.Text == "Sun")
                {
                    ppup.Height = Window.Current.Bounds.Height;
                    ppup.IsOpen = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    ppup1.Height = Window.Current.Bounds.Height;
                    ppup1.IsOpen = true;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ppup1.Height = Window.Current.Bounds.Height;
                ppup1.IsOpen = true;
            }

        }
    }
```

Updated Logic
Below Logic I'm trying issue is image is not comparing

```
if ((image1.Source==new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/LearnColor/Object/ob_" + CI + "_" + LI + ".png"))) &&(objNameWritten1.Text==objnamewritten[LI]))



private void common()
        {

            if (CI > 10)
            {
                CI = 0;
                return;
            }
            if (HeaderName.Text== Headername[CI])
            {
                int LI = 0;
                for (int i = 3*CI+LI; i < 3*(CI+1); LI++)
                {
                    if ((image1.Source==new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/LearnColor/Object/ob_" + CI + "_" + LI + ".png"))) &&(objNameWritten1.Text==objnamewritten[LI]))
                    {
                        ppup.Height = Window.Current.Bounds.Height;
                        ppup.IsOpen = true;
                        CI++;
                        HeaderName.Text = Headername[CI];
                        common();
                    }
                    else if ((image2.Source == new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/LearnColor/Object/ob_" + CI + "_" + LI + ".png"))) && (objNameWritten2.Text == objnamewritten[LI]))
                    {
                        ppup.Height = Window.Current.Bounds.Height;
                        ppup.IsOpen = true;
                        CI++;
                        HeaderName.Text = Headername[CI];
                        common();
                    }
                    else if ((image3.Source == new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/LearnColor/Object/ob_" + CI + "_" + LI + ".png"))) && (objNameWritten3.Text == objnamewritten[LI]))
                    {
                        ppup.Height = Window.Current.Bounds.Height;
                        ppup.IsOpen = true;
                        CI++;
                        HeaderName.Text = Headername[CI];
                        common();
                    }

                }

            }
            else
            {
                ppup1.Height = Window.Current.Bounds.Height;
                ppup1.IsOpen = true;
            }
```

Comment: So what problem are you facing exactly?

Comment: Try to post only the code which is causing your problem. That will make it much easier for people to help you. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: If you refer image then it will be clear .Actually i  want Image container image should change continuously in all three image container on opening of Popup(ppup) eg. ig Headername=yellow and if i tap on imagecontainer1 where image is of "banana" then Popup(ppup) will open and images in three container should change and their name should also change in objNameWritten text variable  according to image in imagecontainer. And Headername should also change  such that One of the Image in Image conatiner should matches with name of HeaderName variable.

Comment: @Bas Actually I am trying for it's Logic but not able to implement that logic .Any idea or would be appreciated.

Comment: @NahuelIanni Please check the updated Logic what i'm trying.

Comment: My advise is to post only the relevant code to reproduce the problem, all other lines add noise. Then post a step by step or list with what you expect to achieve and what you actually get. Otherwise it+s (at lest for me) to tell exactly the problem by just reading your question. When in doubt, check [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)